2018 movie where everyone has chips in their brains and a cop used the chip to see what a suspect could see
I remember that in the movie the people had chips in their brains.
In one scene, a cop used the chip to see what a suspect could see.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

There is also The Final Cut (2004) movie with Robin Williams with similar premise.

This is similar to the Black Mirror episode "Crocodile" but I don't think that's it.  I'm mentioning it only because someone reading this Q might be interested in similar stories. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_(Black_Mirror)

Is this Anon (2018)...?

In a world without anonymity or crime, a detective meets a woman who threatens their security.

The film is set in a near-future society where everyone is required to have an ocular implant called the Mind's Eye, which records everything they see.
The protagonist is a police detective (played by Clive Owen) trying to hunt down a killer who hacks into the Mind's Eye of the victims while the murders are being committed and replaces the victims' POV with his or her own, thereby preventing the police from being able to pull up footage of the killer's face after the fact.
There's a scene in which the protagonist and some other police officers are able to remotely access the Mind's Eye of the prime suspect and see what that person is seeing in real-time, in an effort to ascertain that person's location.



